# Add existing dynamodb table with stream to CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I currently have a dynamodb table that's been in use for a couple of years, originally created in the console. It contains lots of valuable data. It uses a stream to periodically send a snapshot using a lambda trigger of the table to s3 for analytics. The table itself is heavily used by end users to access their data.

I want to migrate my solution into CDK. The options I want to explore:

1. When you use the Table.fromTableArn construct, you don't get access to the table stream arn so it's impossible to attach a lambda trigger. Is there a way around this?
2. Is there a way to clone the dynamoDB table contents in my CDK stack so that my copy will start off in exactly the same state as the original? Then I can add and manage the stream etc in CDK no problem.
3. It's worth checking my assumption that these are the only 2 options.

Comment: Base on the experience of working with RDS, I would like to suggest creating the snapshot/backup of your DynamoDB, and then create a new DynamoDB base on a snapshot from AWS-CDK. Maybe then you would get more control for the DynamoDB.

Comment: Just hit this same thing myself, and it looks like you can use `dynamodb.Table.fromTableAttributes` and pass in `tableStreamArn`. Then the construct will know that streaming is enabled.

Comment: Reg. 1: Indeed, `Table.fromTableName` does not give you access to the stream, you have to use `Table.fromTableAttributes` and specify `tableStreamArn`. Here's a comment in the corresponding Github issue that might be helpful:
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/14046#issuecomment-818556904

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Subscribing Lambda to an existing Dynamo Table:

We don't need to have table created within same stack. We can't use addEventSource on lambda but we can use `addEventSourceMapping` and add necessary policies to Lambda, which is what addEventSource does behind the scenes.

```
const streamsArn =
  "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:110011001100:table/test/stream/2021-03-18T06:25:21.904";
const myLambda = new lambda.Function(this, "my-lambda", {
  code: new lambda.InlineCode(`
  exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('event',event)
    callback(null,'10')
  }
    `),
  handler: "index.handler",
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
});

const eventSoruce = myLambda.addEventSourceMapping("test", {
  eventSourceArn: streamsArn,
  batchSize: 5,
  startingPosition: StartingPosition.TRIM_HORIZON,
  bisectBatchOnError: true,
  retryAttempts: 10,
});
const roleUpdates = myLambda.addToRolePolicy(
  new iam.PolicyStatement({
    actions: [
      "dynamodb:DescribeStream",
      "dynamodb:GetRecords",
      "dynamodb:GetShardIterator",
      "dynamodb:ListStreams",
    ],
    resources: [streamsArn],
  })
);
```

2. Importing existing DynamoDb into CDK:

We re-write dynamo db with same attributes in cdk, synth to generate Cloudformation and use [resource import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html) to import an existing resources into a stack. Here is an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65557458/10186808)

Comment: Awesome! So no need to touch the dynamoDB. That's so well described, even I can understand it.