# Does aws cdk allows to update imported aws dynamodb tables in cloudformation stack

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

I have imported few existing dynaomdb tables in cloduformation stack.

But when I try to update them, aws-cdk tries to create them instead of update & eventually my cdk deployment fails due to a table already exists error.

Comment: What is the actual case?

You want to create them on the fly after checking the existence?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65557316/aws-cdk-working-with-existing-dynamodb-and-streams/65557458#65557458) is an answer